# C# form on top of all windows

Tags: c#, forms

I am launching a C# made form from VBA code inside an Excel workbook.

I'd like this form to appear on top of all other windows/Applications including the Excel workbook.

I'd tried combinations of

```
        Form1 f = new Form1();
        f.Focus();
        f.ShowDialog();
        f.Activate();
        f.Show();
```

But none of them seems to work. Any hints?

Many thanks

JB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a tricky way of doing it: I maximized and then turned back to normal:

```
        Form1 f = new Form1();
        f.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        f.Focus();
        f.Show();
        f.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        Application.Run(f);
```

Comment: This works for me, but why is it that it should be this complex for a simple task of showing and putting a form on top of everything else?  A correct answer yes, but is it the 'best way"?  I have run into this issue and would really like to see a more efficient way to do this....

Answer (score 9):

Set the [TopMost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.topmost.aspx) property to `true`.

```
f.TopMost = true;
```

Comment: Hello John, Thanks for your answer. But I tried that one also and still no window form on top.